# How to Insert null Values in JDate

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jtable

hey guys i m suffering with a problem with NullPointerException i've a jTable wish it have values from those values one Value i put it an Empty value it's a Date this date Can Sometimes Empty means we don't have this Date and Sometimes it's full i tried to Edit this Table so when i click on the Table and click on Button Edit it's shows me a new Frame wish have a Fields to fill them , i want it to populate automaticly it's works very good exept with this empty value wish i've the problem :
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried this code

```
public void fillDateSortie(){
     int row = AdminFW.TableStock.getSelectedRow();
     SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

     String dateInString2 = AdminFW.TableStock.getModel().getValueAt(row, 9).toString();
     try{
            java.util.Date date2 = formatter2.parse(dateInString2);   
        DateSortieStock.setDate(date2);
     }catch(Exception e ){
           javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
     if(DateSortieStock.getDate()==null){
        DateSortieStock.setDate(null);
     }
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code

Answer (score 0):

Try with this .This code not will gives you a exception .

```
   if( ((JTextField)DateSortieStock.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().equals("")){
      DateSortieStock.setDate(null);
    }
```

Hope it helps..